# how to refresh page in a specific time

Tags: php, refresh

i tried this code in my wp page but its not work

```html
<?php
$page = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
$sec = "10";
date("d-m-Y H:i:s");
$time= date("H:i:s");
if($time == "03:40:00")
{
    echo "The new page loading in 10 seconds!";
 header("Refresh: $sec; url=$page");
}
?>
```

Comment: You can do this in client side by using javascript. `setInterval(window.location.reload(), 1000)`

Comment: this is not what i need, i need to refresh in a specific time like : 2020 may 30 20:30:00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this code better i think, thank you Andrew Moore !

```
<script>
function refreshAt(hours, minutes, seconds) {
    var now = new Date();
    var then = new Date();

    if(now.getHours() > hours ||
       (now.getHours() == hours && now.getMinutes() > minutes) ||
        now.getHours() == hours && now.getMinutes() == minutes && now.getSeconds() >= seconds) {
        then.setDate(now.getDate() + 1);
    }
    then.setHours(hours);
    then.setMinutes(minutes);
    then.setSeconds(seconds);

    var timeout = (then.getTime() - now.getTime());
    setTimeout(function() { window.location.reload(true); }, timeout);
}
refreshAt(16,30,0); //Will refresh the page at 4:30pm
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this in PHP, what you can do for such a task is to calculate a time difference and make it in seconds and set the header for the page to be refreshed after the **time diff in seconds**, something like [this](https://3v4l.org/9BG8c):

```
<?php
$page = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
$datetime1 = new DateTime('2020-05-23 18:20:10');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('2020-05-23 18:20:30');
$interval = $datetime2->diff($datetime2);
$diff = $datetime2->getTimestamp() - $datetime1->getTimestamp(); // diff in seconds
// you can just have `redirect` queryString params passed like this.
if(empty($_GET['redirect'])) {
  header("Refresh: $diff; url=$page" . "?redirect=1");
}
```

Something to point out here, is to use  tag to do the refresh in your page instead of using `header()`, it feels cleaner to me as implementation, specially if you already have a template engine:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="20">
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your interest, i don't want every 20 second refresh, i need one time refresh; "2020-05-23 18:30:00" just in time

Comment: Glad to help, you can just have a flag argument, if its there you don't add a refresh header, this can be easily solved.

Comment: could you give me a sample?

Comment: <?php
$page = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
$datetime1 = new DateTime('12:30:10');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('12:30:20');
$interval = $datetime2->diff($datetime2);
$diff = $datetime2->getTimestamp() - $datetime1->getTimestamp(); // diff in seconds
if(empty($_GET['redirect'])) {
  header("Refresh: $diff; url=$page" . "?redirect=1");
}

Comment: I didn't add it without testing, it should work, just make sure that you add the proper query string, check `?` if the `$page` doesn't have query string already, if it does just replace `?` with `&` also the code I added refresh the page after `20` second, replace `$diff` with `2` or `3` and make sure that  `redirect` is not included in `$_GET` if it does change it to something `unique` please try and let me know if it worked or not.

Comment: new code :  <?php
$page = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
$datetime1 = new dateTime('12:37:10');
$datetime2 = new dateTime('12:37:13');
$interval = $datetime2->diff($datetime2);
$diff = $datetime2->getTimestamp() - $datetime1->getTimestamp(); // diff in seconds
if(empty($_GET['redirect'])) {
  header("Refresh:$diff; url=$page" . "$redirect=1");
}

Comment: sorry my friend, I'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 0):

You can place the below code in your header and test. I hope this helps.

```
if ($time == "03:40:00") {
    echo "The new page loading in 10 seconds!";

    echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='3'>";
}
```

Note: The above used meta tag is used to define time intervals to refresh the document itself. Modify the values in "content" attribute of meta tag as you wish to refresh the page

Comment: it didn't work, all the script seen in my page and every 3 seconds it refreshed page

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone, problem solved, i used javascript, function auto-run

```
<script>
(function myFunction() {
    var time = new Date().getHours()
    if( time == "02" ) {
    setTimeout(function(){
  window.location = 'your url';
}, 5000); 
   }
     })();
</script>
```